# OpenCV: UI Manipulating Graph for image processing

Tags: c++, opencv, user-interface

Does OpenCV contain a more sophisticated GUI Tool for Spline visualization? If not what can be used to easily create a curve graph? I need this for adding a 255 Lut Representation to an image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is usually more powerful for the GUI part of the application, and does spline drawing quite easily: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicspathitem.html

I would advice against drawing a LUT using splines though, since the interpolation is irrelevant for discrete data.

Comment: I got the first point, i think this will the way i will have to go, but your second mentioned point doesn't make sense for me. It's not about interpolation, but about shifting the values. at the moment, my Lut is in linear space. i Painted already a sigmoid which gives me a sRgb Lut, but i would like to adjust it. +1 for thinking more than just about the spline

Comment: Ok since you mentioned the GUI I thought you wanted to have spline to display your data. If the splines correspond to real values, you are absolutely right.